# Why do i get duplicate values when adding data to firebase realtime database using kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to display data that a user send to the database but whenever new data is added to the database it displays duplicates of the data that was already in the database like this:

Before I add a new value:
[image]

After I add the word "Apple" and send it to the database i see the following:
[image]

And if i close the app and reopen or refresh the page i get only the tree entries which is what i want like this:

[image]

This is my code to add each entry to the database:

```
    val myRef = database.getReference("User-following").child(currentUid!!)


private fun addCategory() {
    val newCategory = category.text.toString().trim()
    val isValid = validateCategory(newCategory)

    if (isValid) {

        val exists = checkIfCategoryExists(newCategory)

        if (!exists) {
        dismissKeyBoard()
        categorysList.add(newCategory)
        category.text.clear()
        Toast.makeText(this,
            "$newCategory has been added to your list",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        sendDataToDatabase(newCategory)
            } else {
                category.error = "$newCategory has already been added"
            }
    }
}
```

This is my code to pull the data from the database:

```
private fun fetchUsersFollowing() {


    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for( childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                if (!childSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
                    var test = childSnapshot.getValue()
                    val myCategory = CategoryModel()
                    myCategory.setCategories(test.toString())
                    list.add(myCategory)
                } else {
                    val noCategory = CategoryModel()
                    noCategory.setCategories("No Categories added.")
                    list.add(noCategory)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.e("Database Error", error.toString())
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dataSnapshot` that is passed to `onDataChange` always contains the complete data that exists at the node. Since you process that entire snapshot, and add it to `list`, your list will end up with duplicates, triplicates, and more over time.

The simplest solution is to clear the list each time `onDataChange` is called:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        list.clear();
        for( childSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            ...
        }
    }
```